# Xcode 4.3 running application in Portrait

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.3, portrait, device-orientation

Hi im createing a iOS application and i would like it to run on portrait all the time even when i turn it left/right i want it to stay the same here some images of all the settings relevant to portrait.

[image]

[image]

[image]

so thats all the stuff I've set so my question is how do i keep in in portrait even when i tilt it at the moment when it runs it opens in portrait but say if i turn it left it will rotate to landscape.

thanks in advance i will look forward to here from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Use this method to support only portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

Return YES for any orientations you support from this function.

```
 (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```